# Javascript - Return false on an input tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms, return

Just out of curiosity, what would happen if you applied a return false on a input tag?

```
<input type="password" name="psw" onblur="return false;" />
```

Will it prevent the field from being submitted with the rest of the form?

Comment: I think it's a valid question, so voted up and first comment unnecessary.

Comment: @ericosg: First comment is necessary. If a person is curious if some syntax has a certain result, step one is to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

It would not do anything, [blur is not cancelable](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

Returning `false` from a handler simply cancels the default action.

There is no default action that happens on the `blur` event of an `input` element to my knowledge, so there's nothing to cancel.

---

Just to get an idea of what happens when you assign on `on[event]` handler, your element gets a new function assigned to the related property for that event.

So in the case of `onblur`, your element will effectively get:

```
elem.onblur = function(event) {
    return false;
}
```

The body of the function is the string you provided. Older IE will not include the `event` parameter, which is actually helpful in their case.

---

So basically, your string is used as though it was passed to  the `Function` constructor, and the result added to the property.

```
elem.onblur = new Function("event", "return false;")
```